# Magnolia CMS and Keycloak (SSO) integration

Tags: magnolia, keycloak

How to integrate Magnolia CMS with Keycloak?

I need to have a Single Sign On with Keycloak, but haven't found a way (so far I was examining the configuration documentation and wiki pages for Magnolia).

I'm very new to Magnolia so this actually might be a noob question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a side note: Might not be best starter task if you are very new. Consider getting training where authentication and it's configuration is explained at length.

As for the task at hand, you would want to write your own authentication module and place it in the chain of JAAS modules Magnolia/Tomcat will evaluate when authenticating users.

There is similar module written looong time ago for NTLM based authentication that you can take as a blueprint (assuming you are enterprise customer and have access to enterprise code) for what you want to achieve. Otherwise, there's only stuff that is on documentation that might help.
- [NTLM Module](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/NTLM+Connector+module)
- [General security documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Security)

Might be frustrating starting experience tho.

Comment: Most interesting. The actual case is that I have just access to Community Edition. Isn't magnolia open source? Like I should be able to view the sources of NTLM or LDAP connector somewhere?

Comment: Open source - yes, it is. CE is completely out on git.magnolia-cms.com, enterprise modules are open sourced for enterprise clients at same place, just not for general public. So if you are a client, you can see sources of those modules, if you are not, you can see sources of only community modules. However even w/o those sources, you can add custom JAAS authentication module and make SSO work, it will be just tad harder.

Comment: I see. Finally looked into [the comparison of the versions](https://www.magnolia-cms.com/magnolia/features.html#?category_feature_5cab66e9=Interoperability) seems that single sign on is supported only for Enterprise Edition. That's a pity. On a side it's worth mentioning that Keycloak has a JAAS plugin. Anyway thanks for your time @Jan.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know, perhaps all you need to do is add it in and configure the JAAS chain? Would be interesting to know how far you get if you continue to experiment with it.

Comment: Since I don't have access to Enterprise Edition anyway, here's the pointer you can follow if you fancy it ;) https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/securing-client-applications-guide/content/topics/oidc/java/jaas.html